# change marker color based on properties

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, google-maps-markers, openstreetmap

This is my first time here on stackoverflow. I have a doubt. I marked some markers on my map (I used OpenStreetMap). On each marker I put a drop-down menu with choices. Based on these choices, the color of the marker must change.

For example: if choice 1 is clicked, then the marker must be green.

I've tried multiple things but I can't seem to get out of it. Could you give me a hand?

i tried to wrote the code, but the website doesn't let me to put it

P.S. I have declared the marker like that